# Linux users permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora

I have to do the following as homework (on Fedora):

- Make 3 groups S,F,A
- add some users to the groups
- Make a file for each group which only the group members can use.

I logged as root and make in desktop a mkdir S F A and with chmod I give wrx in folder and with chgrp give the group A in dir A , but if I log in with a user from group A I cannot see the dir A in desktop, what i doing wrong?

Also, if I have a folder which can only be accessed by members of its group, can I create a subfolder in it and give access to the subfolder to users who are not in the parent folder's group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Desktop in Gnome (which I assume you are using) is a subdirectory of the user's `$HOME`, specifically `$HOME/Desktop`. So, if you log in as root and create a file or folder on root's Desktop, other users will not see it on *their* desktop. Also, root's $HOME is not accessible to normal users by default.

Instead of creating the directory in root's Desktop, create it in, for example, user A's Desktop.

---

Now, once you have the folders set up, if you want to give access to a subfolder to users who are not in the parent folders group, you will need to allow execution (not read or write) of the parent folder. The only way to access a subfolder is by having execution rights on ts parent. For example, run these commands as `root`:

1. Create a folder and give `rwx` rights to the owner and members of its group, and only `x` permissions to everyone else:

   ```
   mkdir /foo
   chmod 771 /foo/
   ```
2. Create a subdirectory of `/foo` that will be freely accessible to everyone and create a test file in it:

   ```
   mkdir /foo/bar
   chmod 777 /foo/bar/
   touch /foo/bar/file.txt
   chmod 766 /foo/bar/file.txt
   ```

This is what we have created so far:

```
# ls -l / | grep foo
drwxrwx--x   3 root root  4096 Apr 16 14:31 foo
# ls -l /foo
drwxr--r-- 2 root root 4096 Apr 16 14:31 bar
# ls -l /foo/bar
-rwxrw-rw- 1 root root 0 Apr 16 14:47 file.txt
```

So, if I now log in with a user not in `root`'s group, I will not be able to read or write to `/foo` but I *will* be able to read and write to `/foo/bar`:

```
$ whoami
terdon
$ groups
users
$ ls /foo
ls: cannot open directory /foo/: Permission denied
$ ls /foo/bar
file.txt
```

So, to give *any kind* (read,write or execute) access to a subdirectory, you need to at least have execution rights on the parent folder.

Comment: i make a folder A in one user of A's group and i give in Terminal the chgrp A A and chmod 70 A and with ls -l gives me d---rwx--- 1 user A and other

Comment: You want to use chmod `770`, not `70`. You can also use `chmod g+rwx` which is easier to remember.

Comment: @Vagelis doulepse?

Comment: are you know greek?

Comment: are you know greek?
i try chmod g+rwx and again in the user2 is in the same group with user in user a i see the A directori but in the user2 i didnt i use 'chmod g+rwx A'

Comment: @Vagelis, I'm sorry, still not sure what you mean. (an thes grapsto mou sta ellhnika kai to metafrazw)

Comment: αυτό πως θα το κάνω ?
Στους φακέλους που έχουν πρόσβαση αποκλειστικά μόνο τα μέλη της κάθε ομάδας μπορούμε να δημιουργήσουμε μεμονωμένους υποφακέλους ή αρχεία στα οποία να επιτρέψουμε την πρόσβαση (ανάγνωση/εγγραφή) σε χρήστες που δεν είναι μέλη της ομάδας; Περιγράψτε τη διαδικασία.

Comment: @Vagelis I updated my answer, if I understand correctly, this is what you need. Αν δεν καταλαβαίνεις κάτι, άσε μου πάλι κάποιο comment και σου απαντάω στα ελληνικά.

Comment: Thanks for help. Ευχαριστώ πολύ θά ψάχνω να βρω να διαβάσω για να καταλάβω τι ακριβός είναι τα Set User ID (SUID), Set Group ID (SGID) και Sticky bit (STB), μήπως έχει κάποια πηγή για να διαβάσω και να καταλάβω τι είναι?

Comment: why ls -l /home/Sales :Permission denied i make the txt but its deny me

Comment: @Vagelis That depends on the permissions you have on `/home/Sales` and `/home`. If you don't have read access to `/home/Sales` but you _do_ have read access to `/home/Sales/foo`, `ls /home/Sales` will fail but `ls /home/Sales/foo` will work. (Sorry που στα γράφω αγγλικά αλλά είναι η γλώσσα του site).